# Fullcalendar Problems w/ filtering Events in agendaDay-View (works only one time, then no more events exist)

Tags: events, filter, fullcalendar

I have a problem with filtering events:

- I use fullcalender in agendaDay-View
- I use a drop-Down list to select a driver
- I compare the name (it is a property of event-object) with the selected value
  (this part is ok)

Then,

- I remove all Events (`.fullCalendar('removeEvents');`)
- Add the specific events
- (add with renderEvents doesn't work proberly at the moment)
- *And now my problem appears:*
- For the first time it works, however, when I select another 'driver', the events are gone, because of the 'removeEvents'-Action before.

**So, how can I solve this problem, that I can only display the filtered events and keep the other (actualley all events) to filter again for second, third n- time?**

```
$('#' + id).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

was the first idea, however, its brings all back and selected Issues were doubled (and so on).

I'm thankful for every hint.

Comment: + compare properties
`var selEvents = $('#' + id).fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(evt) {
    return evt.driver == oSelDriver.driver;
});`

Comment: * Add the specific events:
`var selEvents.forEach(function(selEvent) {
 var _selEvent = new Array();
 _selEvent['id'] = selEvent.id;
 _selEvent['title'] = selEvent.title;
 _selEvent['start'] = selEvent.start;
 _selEvent['end'] = selEvent.end;
 $('#' + id).fullCalendar("renderEvent", _selEvent, true);
});`

Comment: I would add 'driver' parameter to your events request query from active selected drop-down list and refetch events on change. That way there is no reason to specifically handle events(remove, add), because your function will return only those events that you want to show.

Comment: I'm afraid, that
`mock/events.json?driver=miller --> all events w/ proberty == 'Miller'`
is not possible. (No php in use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think you can solve your problem with fullCalendar's [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) function.

> The function can also return false to completely cancel the rendering of the event.

Your event from events.json should have a property like 'driver_id'.

I would have select field instead of dropdown with option keys being driver ids, values - names or whatever. Lets say it's id would be 'driver_select'.

Then render events like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //...
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        //driver select should have default value assigned or else no events will be rendered
        if ($("#driver_select").val() !== event.driver_id) {
             return false; //do not render other driver events
        }
    }
    //...
});
```

Handle select changes to update

```
$("#driver_select").off('change').on('change', function() {
     $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
});
```

Another approach would be to show all drivers in a timeline. For that you can use [FullCalendar Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/).